# how do I redirect my domain using Amazon aws route 53

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

i have my domain setup on route 53.

How do I redirect it to a different url?

eg route 53 domain is www.robhanover.com 
and i want to redirect it to www.billsandteds.com

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your Route 53 domain with the host you are using.  I don't know what you are using to host it, but assuming you are using S3, you should be able to redirect www.robhanover.com to www.billsandteds.com through configuring it under the bucket's properties.

[image]